# Kafka Consumer Leaving the Consumer Group

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am new to Kafka. I am running into below scenario,
I have inbound and outbound Kafka queue. App read the message from inbound queue, process it(calls 10 downstream services), on success, it puts the message in outbound queue and then commits the message in inbound queue.

1. Happy case, when all the downstream dependencies are working fine, no problem.
2. Bad case, When our hard dependent dependencies(by hard i mean required dependency without my service cannot proceed) failing for say x hours, we do retries and after the results are ready, we put it in outbound queue and then commit it in inbound queue, since there was long wait time between message poll time, we are getting below issue wile committing to inbound queue,

```
WARN [kafka-coordinator-heartbeat-thread]  [Consumer clientId=604dd51a-9b36-4490-aa80-51125bafb465, groupId=abc] This member will leave the group because consumer poll timeout has expired. This means the time between subsequent calls to poll() was longer than the configured max.poll.interval.ms, which typically implies that the poll loop is spending too much time processing messages. You can address this either by increasing max.poll.interval.ms or by reducing the maximum size of batches returned in poll() with max.poll.records. 

INFO [kafka-coordinator-heartbeat-thread] - [Consumer clientId=604dd51a-9b36-4490-aa80-51125bafb465, groupId=abc] Member 604dd51a-9b36-4490-aa80-51125bafb465-e0 sending LeaveGroup request to coordinator zk2-abc.com:9092 (id: 214748 rack: null)
```

There are two problems i am facing,

1. duplicate data processing because message is send to outbound queue and then I am trying to commit to inbound queue.
2. While my consumer is busy processing the message, at some stage it is taken out from consumer list and consumer realises that when trying to commit the data.

I understand the suggested solution is to set "max.poll.interval.ms" as long as the time it requires to process the message but I know the processing time when things are good but not sure when my hard dependency fails as I have to wait for dependent service to respond(with retries). i can set to max time available but not sure whether that is good approach and what is the implication at kafka level.

What I tried,

1. Use pause, poll and resume method of kafka consumer to make sure my consumer is alive
2. use max available time for max.poll.interval.ms to not worry on processing time.

I want to understand what possible solution i have to handle above problem and pros and cons of each.

Answer (score 1):

You could create another thread specifically for the message processing, so the consumer thread won't ever delay when calling `poll()`.

You could create a `pool` of processing threads (big enough not to slow down the consumer thread when trying to allocate the new message), or save the backpressure within an internal structure, such as an `ConcurrentHashMap` or some kind of synchronized `Deque/Queue` with limited size. Your "processor" threads will do the hard work, so the consumer is able to call `poll` in time.

Hope it's helpful, writing it in a rust!

This is taken from the Kafka Consumer [documentation](https://kafka.apache.org/10/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html):

> We have intentionally avoided implementing a particular threading
>   model for processing. This leaves several options for implementing
>   multi-threaded processing of records.
>
> 1. **One Consumer Per Thread**
>
> A simple option is to give each thread its own consumer instance. Here are the pros and cons of this approach:
>   PRO: It is the easiest to implement PRO: It is often the fastest as no
>   inter-thread co-ordination is needed PRO: It makes in-order processing
>   on a per-partition basis very easy to implement (each thread just
>   processes messages in the order it receives them). CON: More consumers
>   means more TCP connections to the cluster (one per thread). In general
>   Kafka handles connections very efficiently so this is generally a
>   small cost. CON: Multiple consumers means more requests being sent to
>   the server and slightly less batching of data which can cause some
>   drop in I/O throughput. CON: The number of total threads across all
>   processes will be limited by the total number of partitions.
>
> 2. **Decouple Consumption and Processing**
>
> Another alternative is to have one or more consumer threads that do all data consumption and hands
>   off ConsumerRecords instances to a blocking queue consumed by a pool
>   of processor threads that actually handle the record processing. This
>   option likewise has pros and cons: PRO: This option allows
>   independently scaling the number of consumers and processors. This
>   makes it possible to have a single consumer that feeds many processor
>   threads, avoiding any limitation on partitions. CON: Guaranteeing
>   order across the processors requires particular care as the threads
>   will execute independently an earlier chunk of data may actually be
>   processed after a later chunk of data just due to the luck of thread
>   execution timing. For processing that has no ordering requirements
>   this is not a problem. CON: Manually committing the position becomes
>   harder as it requires that all threads co-ordinate to ensure that
>   processing is complete for that partition. There are many possible
>   variations on this approach. For example each processor thread can
>   have its own queue, and the consumer threads can hash into these
>   queues using the TopicPartition to ensure in-order consumption and
>   simplify commit.

Comment: Thanks @aran, at present I am one consumer per thread due to nature of problem we are working, thanks for point 2, will think on that.